# How to prove that $B$ is non-degenerate? does the question has typo?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, multilinear-algebra, bilinear-form

Here is the question I want to prove:

Let $V = M_2(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of all $2\times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}.$ Show that $$B(X,Y) = det(X+Y) - det(X) - det(Y)$$

Where $X,Y \in V,$ is a symmetric nondegenerate bilinear form on $V.$

I tried to prove linearity but it did not work. Also, I was unable to prove nondegeneracy. Could someone tell me if there is a typo in this question please?

Comment: Hint: $B(X,Y)$ is identically equal to $\operatorname{trace}(\operatorname{adj}(X)Y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no typo in the question. If
$$
X=\pmatrix{x_{11}&x_{12}\\x_{21}&x_{22}}\ ,\ Y=\pmatrix{y_{11}&y_{12}\\y_{21}&y_{22}}\ ,
$$
then
\begin{align}
B(X,Y)&=\big(x_{11}+y_{11}\big)\big(x_{22}+y_{22}\big)-\big(x_{12}+y_{12}\big)\big(x_{21}+y_{21}\big)\\
&\hspace{3em}-x_{11}x_{22}+x_{12}x_{21}-y_{11}y_{22}+y_{12}y_{21}\\
&=x_{11}y_{22}+x_{22}y_{11}-x_{12}y_{21}-x_{21}y_{12}\\
&=\pmatrix{x_{11}&x_{12}&x_{21}&x_{22}}\pmatrix{0&0&0&1\\0&0&-1&0\\0&-1&0&0\\1&0&0&0}\pmatrix{y_{11}\\y_{12}\\y_{21}\\y_{22}}\ .
\end{align}
It follows that $\ B\ $ is bilinear, and
$$
M=\pmatrix{0&0&0&1\\0&0&-1&0\\0&-1&0&0\\1&0&0&0}
$$
is [its matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form#Coordinate_representation) with respect to the basis
$$
\left\{\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0},\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0},\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}\right\}
$$
of $\ M_2(\mathbb{R})\ $. The symmetry and non-degeneracy of $\ B\ $ follow from those of its matrix $\ M\ $.

Comment: Why using this if we already have a formula given in the question?I think we are required to use it in the proof.... am I correct?

Comment: But  the formula given in the question  *is* used in the proof suggested by the hint. To find $\ M\ $, you've got to expand the expression given for $\ B(X,Y)\ $ out to express it in terms of the entries of $\ X\ $ and $\ Y\ $.

Comment: But this is not what is required in the question. I do not understand how your hint will help me, could you clarify please?

Comment: I have really a problem in proving nondegeneracy so if you include this in your answer would really  appreciate this

Comment: I've now given full details of one proof of the required results.